# Active Directory Member Of Custom Pull Script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, active-directory

I put together this script over 5 years ago now and since have forgotten what I did or how I did it...

For some context, the below script which runs from a .bat file was used to enter a user's display name and then using dsquery and dsget, along with Get-Content from PowerShell commands. About 6 months ago this script stopped working and just crashes and fails with a brief error that it getting stuck on this line to my understanding:

```
dsquery user forestroot -name "%lookforuser%">"%userprofile%\Desktop\usertemp.txt"
```

The %lookforuser% variable is set earlier in the script, see below for full source code:

```
@echo off
title Get AD Groups For User
set /p lookforuser=Enter Username (Surname, Firstname):
set lookforuser2=%lookforuser: =%

echo %lookforuser%
echo %lookforuser2%

dsquery user forestroot -name "%lookforuser%">"%userprofile%\Desktop\usertemp.txt"

set /p usercn=<"%userprofile%\Desktop\usertemp.txt"

dsget user %usercn% -memberof>"%userprofile%\Desktop\usertemp.txt"

Powershell -Command "(Get-Content %userprofile%\Desktop\usertemp.txt) -replace '\"CN=','' ^| Out-File -encoding ASCII %userprofile%\Desktop\usertemp.txt"

Powershell -Command "(Get-Content %userprofile%\Desktop\usertemp.txt) -replace ',OU=','*' | Out-File -encoding ASCII %userprofile%\Desktop\usertemp.txt"

for /f "delims=*, tokens=1" %%A IN (%userprofile%\Desktop\usertemp.txt) do echo %%A>>"%userprofile%\Desktop\%lookforuser2%.txt"

del "%userprofile%\Desktop\usertemp.txt"
```

Long story short, can anyone help me figure out what's gone on, has my parent company changed something to force this not to work, or has MS changed something that no longer allows this script to run, really stumped and not sure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, even if you have something similar that works in Powershell

Please see error in command prompt below:

```
Get-Content : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\mcguirkd\Desktop\usertemp.txt' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:2
+ (Get-Content C:\Users\mcguirkd\Desktop\usertemp.txt) -replace '"CN=', ...
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\mcguirkd\Desktop\usertemp.txt:String) [Get-Content], ItemNotFo
   undException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand

Out-File : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\mcguirkd\Desktop\usertemp.txt'.
At line:1 char:75
+ ... '"CN=','' | Out-File -encoding ASCII C:\Users\mcguirkd\Desktop\userte ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Out-File], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand

Get-Content : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\mcguirkd\Desktop\usertemp.txt' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:2
+ (Get-Content C:\Users\mcguirkd\Desktop\usertemp.txt) -replace ',OU=', ...
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\mcguirkd\Desktop\usertemp.txt:String) [Get-Content], ItemNotFo
   undException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand

Out-File : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\mcguirkd\Desktop\usertemp.txt'.
At line:1 char:76
+ ... ,OU=','*' | Out-File -encoding ASCII C:\Users\mcguirkd\Desktop\userte ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Out-File], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand
```

Comment: Your question is practically unreadable. Please use the [Edit] button together with the built in formatting tools, to make it so. Thank you.

Comment: What does `type "%userprofile%\Desktop\usertemp.txt"` return?

Comment: @Stephan Hi Stephan,

It returns The system cannot find the path specified, for some contex there isn't the usertemp.txt file on my desktop, the script would run, use it and by the end of the search for example my name, the document would be renamed to McGuirk,Daniel

Hope that makes sense

Comment: @Stephan Nope, where do you get this from? Should be:

Comment: C:\Users\mcguirkd\Desktop\usertemp.txt

Comment: ups - sorry, my last comment was meant for another (similar) question. I'll delete it.